# gpu acceleration for opencv on android

Tags: android, opencv

I am currently researching on using opencv on an android embedded platform. I need to process input from several usb cameras in realtime and will need gpu acceleration to handle it e.g. opencl, cuda etc.

What's the current state of gpu acceleration support for opencv targeting arm gpus like mali, andreno etc?

Comment: Have you found an answer to the question?